# python using "with" along with smbus2 so exits cleanly. Anyway to tell if exception occurred?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the following in python 3:

```
def adread():
    with SMBus(1) as bus:  
        x=bus.read_byte_data(0x4b,0x40)

    return x
```

The "with" is nice if an exception occurs since it exits cleanly.
Is there a way to tell if an exception has occurred during this bus read?

or do I have to use try-except instead of with to know if exception occurred?

Answer (score 0):

A `with` statement is basically using the `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions of a class, so it can be simulated like this:

```
class a():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __enter__(self):
        return(self.val)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        raise Exception("Error")


try:
    with a(1) as b:
        print(b)

except Exception as e:
    print("Exception occured", e)
```

Your function would look similar to:

```
def adread():
    try:
        with SMBus(1) as bus:  
            x=bus.read_byte_data(0x4b,0x40)
    except:
        # Safe/fault value for x

    return x
```